# Custom .NET Core service factory with auto dispose features

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-5

In .NET 5/.NET 6 we typically get our services from the ServiceProvider directly.

But in some cases this is not possible and we need to create a service factory. We inject the service factory into our services and then, within the service, the service factory creates instances on demand. A public example would be `HttpClientFactory` (for demonstrating the thought).

The usual use case would be if a service needs to have multiple instances of a service and the instances need to be (pre)configured within the using service.

---

My way to implement this looks as follows:

```
// appsettings.json
"MyServiceFactory": {
  "Instances": {
    "Instance1": {
      "Option1": "Hi",
      "Option2": "there"
    },
    "Instance2": {
      "Option1": "Thanks",
      "Option2": "for helping"
    }
  }
}

// the options class to bind
public class MyServiceFactoryOptions
{
  public Dictionary<string, MyServiceOptions> Instances { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, MyServiceOptions>(); 
}

// the factory implementation
public class MyServiceFactory : IMyServiceFactory
{
  
  public readonly ILoggerFactory LoggerFactory;
  public readonly ILogger<MyServiceFactory> Logger;
  public readonly MyServiceFactoryOptions Options;
  
  public MyServiceFactory(ILogger<MyServiceFactory> logger, IOptions<MyServiceFactoryOptions> options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
  {
    LoggerFactory = loggerFactory   ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(loggerFactory));
    Logger        = logger          ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
    Options       = options.Value;
  }
  
  public IMyService CreateInstance(string name)
  {   
    if (Options.Instances.TryGetValue(name, out MyServiceOptions options))
    {
      ILogger<MyService> logger = LoggerFactory.CreateLogger<MyService>();
      IOptions<MyService> iOptions = Microsoft.Extensions.Options.Options.Create(options);
      return new MyService(logger, iOptions);
    }
    else
    {
      throw new Exception($"Config is missing instance configuration for {name}");
    }
  }
  
}

//the service registration
services
  .AddOptions<MyServiceFactoryOptions>()
  .BindConfiguration("MyServiceFactory");

services.TryAddTransient<MyServiceFactory>();
```

And the `CreateInstance(string name)` method actually works creating the instances with the given configuration as desired.

---

The problem rises when `MyService` needs to be disposed when the ASP.NET server is closed.

Typically

1. the (my) service implements `IDisposable`
2. the instance is created via the `ServiceProvider`
3. the instance is injected via the constructor
4. `Dispose` gets called when the server is shut down

In my implementation `Dispose` seems to be never called.
A hint why that my could be comes from [Andrew Locks's article - Four ways to dispose IDisposable](https://andrewlock.net/four-ways-to-dispose-idisposables-in-asp-net-core/#automatically-disposing-services-leveraging-the-built-in-di-container).

As I understand it right now the problem is that the instances are not created via the `ServiceProvider` and therefor `Dispose` is not called.

Am I right and is there a way to get `Dispose` called?

Comment: can you share an example how you instantiate IMyService?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but in a consuming service I use the constructor injection getting the factory injected and then call Factory.CreateInstance.

Comment: yes that's what I was asking, because the issue is most likely there. The IoC container will only auto dispose of services it created, so if you inject the service itself in the constructor. If you manually call the factory.CreateInstance method, then you will have to manually dispose of the service you created, preferably by making the enclosing service disposable and disposing of the myService in it's dispose method